# Need to update minimum SDK version - how to properly separate active and inactive users via Play Developer stats?

Tags: android, google-play

I need to include a new library into the project, but it's min SDK version is 14. The app (150k users) min SDK version is 10.

I opened Play Developer stats and saw that there are approx 3% of users with version lower than 14. This is a paid app and I cannot simply exclude them.

[image]

Can anyone tell me if these statistics include total number of devices installed this app or **active number of devices actually using this app**?

I am confused because I cannot find device with API older than 14 in Crashlytics logs (they represent actual users using app on the daily basis).

So can I trust Crashlytics and simply declare that these 3% are non-active users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

title says it all: "Current Installs".

Those are the number of devices that have your app installed. Maybe they even never opened the app or maybe opened it a couple of times but never again.

Yes, Crashalitics stats will be based on active users, not just instalations.

On a side note you have alternatives:

1. you can force the API to 10 and check during runtime the device API level before calling anything on the library that will use it. (if possible)
2. you can use build flavours on gradle to only include those new features from this library on one build, but not the other.
3. you can upgrade the app with the new API, but keep the old version on Google Play (old devices will still be able to download the old version of your app).

Comment: I was afraid of you would say that. One note about option 3: did you refer to multiple APK feature on Play Developer?

Comment: Yes. We use on our app and it's fine. Some ppl still download the gingerbread version, even though it haven't had an update since almost an year.